# Stationary Points of A Function of Two Variables

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

[image]

I am trying to find and classify the stationary points of this function. I have make some calculations but it have been very complex. If you have an idea and solution i will be happy. Thank you

Comment: have you got the partial derivatives?

Comment: yes but i have taken for second after it became complex

Answer (score 1):

i have got the following system
$$8+8x_1-8x_2-8x_1x_2+2x_2^2+2x_1x_2^2=0$$
$$-4-8x_1-4x_1^2+2x_2+4x_1x_2+2x_1^2x_2=0$$
Have you got this?
solving the first equation for $x_1$ we get
$$x_1(8-8x_2+2x_2^2)=8x_2-8-2x_2^2$$ 
have you got this?
a last comment, your function can be written as
$$f(x_1,x_2)=(-4-2x_1+x_2+x_1x_2)(-2x_1+x_2+x_1x_2)$$

Comment: yes after that i could not decide how to determine the stationary points

Comment: the first equation is linear in $x_1$ solve this equation for $x_1$ and plug this in the second equation

Comment: thank you so much.i have found x1=-1 and x2=2 how can i find the stationary points from here?

Comment: i have $x_1=-2,x_2=2$?

Comment: i have taken for x1 paranthesis and then x1+1=0

Comment: yes than x=-1 i found

Comment: but you must also consider the case if $$8-8x_2+2x_2^2=0$$

Comment: ok then how can i decide the stationary points

Comment: you must use the second derivative test, i will send you a link

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html

Comment: thank you can you share the solution also?

Comment: i will check my solution again, maybe it was a typo

Comment: ok i have made a typo, it is $x_1=-1,x_2=2$ congratulations!

Comment: thank you. can you share the second derivative test result also?

Comment: ok i will try it, some minutes please

Comment: thank you so much. im waiting

Comment: i got $0$ for the second derivative test, but i will check my calculations